# How to stop text from overflowing on Java FX

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I am outputting text to a textarea in Java FX but how do I prevent the user from using a scroll bar to navigate to the end of text and stop the text from overflowing?  (please see the image below)

[Java FX text overflow image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYl91.png)

Below is the code in my GUI.fxml class

```
<Tab closable="false" text="Second Link">
     <content>
        <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.5" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="200.0">
          <items>
            <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
                 <children>
                    <TextArea fx:id="secondText" layoutX="22.0" layoutY="48.0" prefHeight="511.0" prefWidth="571.0" />
                    <TextField layoutX="215.0" layoutY="14.0" text="           Original Text" />
                 </children></AnchorPane>
            <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="363.0" prefWidth="292.0">
                 <children>
                    <TextField layoutX="215.0" layoutY="14.0" text="             Summary" />
                    <TextArea layoutX="16.0" layoutY="48.0" prefHeight="511.0" prefWidth="571.0" />
                 </children>
              </AnchorPane>
          </items>
        </SplitPane>
     </content>
</Tab>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `wrapText=true` to you `TextArea` elements. It will wrap the text to the new line instead of scrolling.

Comment: Ah so simple! Thank you so much